# Right way to send specific PHP variable back to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm kinda confused how to solve this problem in a right way..

This is jQuery function I intend to use. Runs on 1.7.2 jQuery, PHP 5.2.

```
    $(function() {
        var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 5000);

//var categoryid = ;??

        function showDiv()
        {

        $.post("check4_new_data.php?categoryid="+encodeURIComponent(categoryid),
        function(response)
        {
            $('#awaiting').fadeOut(400); //cosmetics, nothing important
            $('#posting1').html(unescape(response));
            $('#posting1').fadeIn(200);
        });

       }
    });
```

**Question:**

There is a PHP variable `$categoryid` set when PHP page loads and.. this function needs it. So, how to send `$categoryid` back to jQuery in a right, safest way?

Note:Ive been using cookie as first test to keep `categoryid` present for PHP, but then all opened (and different) pages started to load up same data (according to latest page visited).

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<div id="posting1" data-category="my_category">
    ...
</div>
```

This way, your markup and JavaScript can be separated completely. So you can fetch the category for the related post you are trying to refresh:

```
var category = $('#posting1').attr('data-category');
$.post(
    "check4_new_data.php?categoryid="+encodeURIComponent(category), 
    function (response) {
        $("#posting1").html(response);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `json_encode`;

```
var categoryid = <?php echo json_encode($categoryid);?>;
```

`json_encode` always produces a JavaScript-safe encoding. Even for complex variables and multidimensional arrays, and it's type-safe (for scalars at least).

Comment: Thank you Frits! I will use this on IM which has the same problem. Many many thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
json_encode;

  var categoryid = <?php echo json_encode($categoryid);?>;
```

For further details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php